# htaccess: friendly url - trailing slash and "fake subdirectories"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make fake-subdirectories with htaccess (`fakefolder/forget-password` with rewrite mod), but it doesn't really working for me...

I have this url:

`parent-directory/index.php?version=1&do=forget-password&email=example@domain.com&token=85085ab92fcfd5dada280c73f7f494ec`

`*` note: the 'email' variable is being verified with mysql, and I use `filter_var` in case the value is an email so it can be also username instead (`email=username`). `parent-directory` is a real directory. `version` is dynamic, and can be 2 or 3 or string, and show a different result, so in this case `version=1` is `fakefolder`. `version=2` and any other value can be anything else (`fakefolder2`)

and this `htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Set configuration file
php_value auto_prepend_file configuration.inc.php

# Start Rewriting
RewriteBase /parent-directory/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^fakefolder$ index.php?version=1 [QSA,L]
```

if I try to make something like this: `RewriteRule ^([a-z])$/forget-password$ index.php?version=$1&do=forget-password [QSA,L]` it's not working, or showing 404

Is it possible? (if yes, then can it be multileveled? e.g. `index.php?version=1&do=forget-password&email=example@domain.com -> ([a-z])$/forget-password/username` instead of `fakefolder/forget-password?email=...`)?

Please excuse my english and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
# Set configuration file
php_value auto_prepend_file configuration.inc.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# Start Rewriting
RewriteBase /parent-directory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/forget-password/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&do=forget-password&email=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/forget-password/?$ index.php?version=$1&do=forget-password [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^fakefolder/?$ index.php?version=1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, i'll check it now

Comment: Update: i've checked it - the last rule (`RewriteRule ^fakefolder/?$ index.php?version=1 [QSA,L,NC]`) worked but the rest (`RewriteRule ^([a-z])/forget-password/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&do=forget-password&email=$1 [QSA,L,NC] RewriteRule ^([a-z])/forget-password/?$ index.php?version=$1&do=forget-password [QSA,L,NC]`) didn't, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Update: i forgot the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` and adding `[OR]` after `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d`, i'll try it again. Another update: I added but still 404